# Using the for loop to print a pattern in Java - My solution is not accepted by an autograder

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm doing a quiz on an online MOOC and one of the questions is to generate a pattern using the for loop as below: 
[added an image as the pattern is not displaying correctly below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYDNV.png)

```
*********
 *******
  *****
   ***
    *
```

I need to fill in the blank on the given code to generate the pattern above:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 1; j <= i-1; j++) {
         out.print(" ");
       }
       for (int j = 1; j <= __________; j++) {
          out.print("*");
       }
       out.println();
    }
```

My solution is 11-(2*i) but it's not accepted by the auto grader. I have ran this code on an online Java compiler and it does produce the expected result. So I'm not sure what is wrong with my solution. Can someone help? I'm also curious to know of any other solution for this question.

Thank you in advance for responding.

Comment: Thank you for editing @Jens. May I know how to insert asterisks with proper formatting on my question?

Comment: Have you tried `11-2*i` (no parenthesis) / `11-i*2` / etc? I'm not sure of MOOC requires exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Yiu have to add `11-2*i` at the underline place:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= 11-2*i; j++) {
            out.print("*");
        }
        out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int j = 9; j > 0; j -= 2) {
    for (int k = j; k < 9; k += 2) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int i = j; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

this code provides the pattern you want. its not entirely your code

Comment: Thank you but I can't edit the given code. I'm only supposed to fill in the blanks.

Comment: then use what kennytm posted as comment. that is also working